# Multi-signature time-locking script

Tags: multisig

I am trying to create a multi-signature time locking script similar to [this example](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/blob/master/doc/reference/simple-scripts.md#example-of-using-a-script-for-time-locking). I want to lock assets into a script to be released at a later date.

```
{
    "type": "all",
    "scripts": [
        {
            "type": "after",
            "slot": 55596400
        },
        {
            "type": "sig",
            "keyHash": "..."
        }
    ]
}
```

According to the docs linked above, I have to add the `--invalid-before [slot]` argument, where `slot` is greater than or equal to the value specified in my script (`55596400` in my example). By doing that, I cannot submit the transaction until that slot number.

I was hoping to be able to lock the assets into a script address that could then be redeemed by the holder of the key specified in the script after the given slot. So my questions are:

1. Is that not possible with a multisig script?
2. If not, what is the purpose of a time-locked multisig script? I guess I could give the assembled transaction with the needed witness off-chain, but then nothing prevents me from spending the assets before the given slot.
3. Is there a way to do what I'm wanting to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It is possible
2. The script used in the above example is used to construct an address from which funds UTXOs can only be used if they follow the logic specified by the script.
3. Looks like you've already done it! Just continue following the instructions in your linked example for creating and funding the script address. Be sure to test with a round trip before committing any large funds!

Comment: Thank you! I was running into an error that looked exactly like this https://forum.cardano.org/t/transaction-submit-error-on-testnet-for-time-locked-policy-script/57449 and got off the path. I was just witnessing with the wrong key. :( I appreciate you confirming that what I was wanting to do is possible and for pointing me in the right direction.